# Tratamento de campo no Model antes de gravar no banco de dados (Python + Django)

Tags: python, django, getters-setters, model, decorator-pattern

Estou tentando realizar uma criptografia de senha utilizando Python 3.7 e o Django 2.1.

Olhando a documentação do Python, Django e algumas respostas aqui no StackOverflow, cheguei no código da seguinte forma, porém, o campo da senha é gravado em branco no banco de dados.

Esse é um formulário web de cadastro de usuário e antes de realizar a gravação no banco de dados, gostaria de realizar alguns tratamentos na senha informada pelo usuário.

Alguém teria alguma dica, documentação, etc que possa auxiliar na correção desse problema?

Segue abaixo os códigos:

**models.py**

```py
    from django.db import models

    class Usuario(models.Model):
            nome = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
            sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
            email = models.EmailField(unique = True)
            usuario = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique = True)
            _senha = models.CharField(max_length = 254, db_column = 'senha')
            criacao = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)
            ativo = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    @property
    def senha(self):
            return self._senha

    @senha.setter
    def senha(self, value):
            self._senha = value
```

**views.py**

```py
    from django.views.generic import CreateView

    from .models import Usuario
    from .forms import CadastrarUsuario

    class IndexView(CreateView):
            template_name = 'cadastro/index.html'
            model = Usuario
            form_class = CadastrarUsuario
            success_url = '/cadastro'

    def form_valid(self, form):
            form.send_email()
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

**forms.py**

```py
    from django import forms

    from .models import Usuario

    class CadastrarUsuario(forms.ModelForm):

            nome = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'input_field'}),label = 'Nome')
            sobrenome = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'input_field'}), label = 'Sobrenome')
            email = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'input_field'}), label = 'E-mail')
            confirma_email = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'input_field'}), label = 'Confirmar E-mail')
            usuario = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'input_field'}), label = 'Login')
            senha = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'class': 'input_field'}), label = 'Senha')
            confirma_senha = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'class': 'input_field'}), label = 'Confirmar senha')

    class Meta:
            model = Usuario
            fields = ['nome', 'sobrenome', 'email', 'confirma_email', 'usuario', 'senha', 'confirma_senha']

    def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super().clean()

            senha = cleaned_data.get('senha')
            confirma_senha = cleaned_data.get('confirma_senha')

            email = cleaned_data.get('email')
            confirma_email = cleaned_data['confirma_email']

            if senha != confirma_senha:
                    raise forms.ValidationError('Senha não confere! Digite a mesma senha nos campos Senha e Confirmar Senha.')

            if email and confirma_email:
                    if email != confirma_email:
                            raise forms.ValidationError('E-Mail não confere! Digite o mesmo e-mail nos campos E-mail e Confirma E-mail')

            return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu utilizo o `django.contrib.auth.hashers` para lidar com senhas. Basicamente você pode utilizar o método `make_password` e `check_password` para trabalhar com criptografia.

Exemplo:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password

senha_criada_pelo_usuario = '123abc'
senha_criptografada = make_password(password=senha_criada_pelo_usuario, salt=None, hasher='pbkdf2_sha256')

# para verificar se a senha corresponde a criptografada:
senha_informada_no_login = '123abc'
corresponde = check_password(password=senha_informada_no_login, encoded=senha_criptografada)
if corresponde:
    # <seu codigo>
    pass
```

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, não ficou exatamente como eu esperava! Mas de qualquer forma sua dica resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado!